# scripted pdf code review

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, pdf, evince

### What I try to achieve

I need to review a bunch of C source code spread out into dozen of directories. I already have a bash script which does the following: It searches for all source codes in the directory I'm interested in. For each code found, it generates a pdf (where the source file is) using the following command:

```
a2ps $source -R --columns=1 --prologue='color' --line-numbers=1 -T2 -M A4 \
  --chars-per-line=100 --borders=no --encoding=iso1 -o - | \
  ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - $dest
```

Then it opens this generated pdf with a PDF viewer to let me review it using sticky notes. I then save it, close it and the script do the same for the next c source code, etc.

This way I can review all the source codes in an automatic way and distribute the review back in a handy pdf format.

### Where it fails

I can't find a proper PDF reader which allows me to do exactly what I've mentioned above. Basically what I've tried :

#### Evince

Don't allow to save the sticky notes in the same file, I need to "Save as..." and evince then open the previous location used and not the location of the current pdf. This force me to manually navigates trought the directories to find the source pdf to override it.

#### Xournal

It don't have sticky notes and this is mandatory for me.

#### Okular

The sticky notes are not visible into Adobe Reader which is mandatory for me too.

#### Adobe Reader 9

This old version for Linux (thanks Adobe) don't support sticky notes.

### Therefore what I need

To summarize what I've said above, I need a PDF reader that is :

- able to *save* the annotated pdf directly or at least *save as* it in the same directory directly
- using official pdf sticky notes
- creates sticky notes that are visible into, at least, *Adobe Reader* and *evince*

Your help is much appreciated has it could save me a lot of time! Also feel free to suggest a whole different workflow idea if it's matching my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick idea involving evince and your bash script:

```
 dir=$(dirname $source)
 rm -f ~/evince_save
 ln -s $dir ~/evince_save
```

And when you "Save as" in evince, save into `~/evince_save`.  As you observe, evince will use the same directory every time, but the automation script will have replaced its link each time; you don't have to do any navigating and the file ends up in the right place.

The `rm` removes the symlink and not the directory; `-f` means no error if `~/evince_save` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

If these C source file are not yet under revision control bring them under revision control (mercurial would be my suggestion). If they are under some outdated revision control system (SVN, CVS) convert the source base.

(After that,) clone the repository and make branch 'revision', use the normal editor with syntax highlighting (should be as readable as your PDFs) and some recognizable way to mark your comments:

```
/*CID: need to review the following in more detail */
```

The review feedback can be given by committing and pushing your changes and the others can just do a (graphical diff) to see what your comments where (per file or for a bunch of files).

You don't have to mark the comments, but if someone merges your 'changes' in your comments are more easily recognised.

(I am not entirely sure why you find the PDF format handy.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I need the PDF format for it _frozen_ state. It's for evaluating purpose so the code should not be changed.